# Website oreloading issue

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask question in regarding to my website I am currently trying to finish. The issue is following:
When for example index.html is opening preloader is loading all elements, but sidebar menu is appearing already even during loading.
Does anybody know, where the issue might be?

```js
  $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
   $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
   $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
   $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  })
```

```css
#preloader {
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background-color:#fff; /* change if the mask should be a color other than white */
 z-index:99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#status {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally on the screen */
 top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically on the screen */
 background-image:url(../img/status.gif); /* path to your loading animation */
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
 <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well really the question is how are you "hiding" the body contents? overflow is likely NOT a good strategy, so that's likely where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are referring to the (as of jQuery 1.8) [deprecated `.load()` method](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/). The [current method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) does something else.

What you are looking for is [this](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```